# Teleportation without classical channel

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-teleportation

In an article [on vixra](http://vixra.org/abs/1605.0260), there is a statement that teleportation of information can be done without the use of classical communication channel. I know that this is forbidden by the no-communication theorem but I cannot see what is the concrete reason.

Shortly the idea is:
One of the electrons from an EPR pair (Alice) is placed in an homogeneous magnetic field. 
Because the spin projection expectation value $S$ on $x$-axis of this electron (which is known fact from nuclear magnetic resonance) varies with time as $\cos(Bt)$, Alice can control it thereby controlling the spin projection expectation value $S$ on $x$ of the other electron (Bob) from the pair.

So if Alice choses time $t$ so that $\cos$ near 1, and has a few number of EPR electrons most of the time when she measures the spin on $x$-axis she will get $+1/2$, whereby the distant electron (Bob) will show $-1/2$ predominantly. Apperently Bob will know what Alice’s choice is.
Any suggestion what is going wrong here? But please be concrete!

Answer (score 2):

If Alice observes an electron from a maximally entangled EPR pair, the expectation value of the spin is always
$$\langle \vec S \rangle = 0,$$
not the cosine indicated by the OP. It's because the EPR pair always has the 50% probability for one value of the spin and 50% probability for the opposite value of the spin. These odds are true regardless of the axis with respect to which the spin is measured, and these odds cannot be changed in any way.

The two individual terms in the entangled state have the property that their Alice's $\langle S_z\rangle$ behaves as the cosine, but the coefficients of these two cosines have the same absolute value and the opposite sign, so that the expectation value of the spin exactly cancels in the whole entangled state.

The magnetic field used by Alice doesn't change anything qualitative about the character of the entanglement at all. It only transforms the 2-component wave function for her electron by a $U(2)$ transformation that may be calculated by integrating the effect of the magnetic field on the electron.

But the entangled state always has the form
$$ \frac{ |\alpha,ALICE\rangle |up,BOB\rangle + |\beta,ALICE\rangle |down,BOB\rangle   }{\sqrt{2}} $$
for some pure state $\alpha,\beta$ of Alice's electron. So the situation always differs from the normal situation without magnetic fields by a trivial transformation – basically by a convention which states in the 2-dimensional space of Alice's electron's spin states are called $\alpha,\beta$. Regardless of the magnetic fields, Alice is always 50-50 uncertain about the result she will get and she can't affect the 50-50 odds in any way, either.

Comment: Lubos Motl  thanks a lot. But do you mean expectation value for spin projection is always zer0, or just when the electron is entangled? Because in the article I cited above it is shown (calculated) that it is hcos(`Bt)/2 on x and hsin(`Bt)/2 on y.  from <psi|sigma1|psi> and <psi|sigma2|psi>. Sorry I don't use LaTex otherwise I would reproduce them here.

Comment: Ah, I found that is true as is calculated. Look here: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node91.html#e10.65 -- the result is the same with alfa= 90 (initial spin along B)

Comment: It's only zero for the entangled state. The pure one-electron states indeed do like to have nonzero expectation values - the projection of the spin with respect to one axis is always the maximum one - and indeed, in the magnetic field, there is the (co)sine dependence on time for a pure 1-spin state. But the EPR state is a 2-spin pure state which effectively translates to a mixed state for 1 spin ("trace over" the other spin), and all the expectation values of spins are zero in that mixed state.